# how to vectorize julia Convex inequality constraints

Tags: julia, convex

I'm trying to vectorize an inequality constraint comparing two `Convex` types. On one side, I have `Convex.MaxAtom`s, and on the other side, I have `Variable`s. I want to do something like the following:

```
using Convex
N = 10
t = Variable(1)
v = Variable(N)
x = Variable(1)
z = rand(100)

problem = minimize(x)
problem.constraints += [t >= 0]

ccc = Vector{Convex.MaxAtom}(N)
for i = 1:N
    c = -(1. + minimum(x.*z))
    cc = t + c
    ccc[i] = max(cc,0.)
end
problem.constraints += [ccc <= v]
```

but I'm getting the following error on the final constraint:

`ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Complex{Int64}, ::Int64)`

I'm not sure where the `Int64` types are coming in. Is there a better way of adding this constraint besides looping through and adding individual comparisons like

```
for i = 1:N
      problem.constraints += [ccc[i] <= v[i]]
end
```

I'm trying to avoid this because eventually my 10 will be much larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (thanks to Dr. Udell), it works to vectorize as

```
c = -(1. + xisim + minimum(x.*z))
cc = t + c
ccc = max(cc,0.)
problem.constraints += [ccc <= v]
```